# Об употреблении "двоицы" вместо "упорядоченной пары"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Разумно ли употреблять слово "двоица" вместо словосочетания "упорядоченная пара"?

Примеры употребления слов "двоица" и "упорядоченная пара"

- Двоица (0, 1) отличается от двоицы (1, 0), а пара {0, 1} не отличается от пары {1, 0}.
- Упорядоченная пара (0, 1) отличается от упорядоченной пары (1, 0) , а неупорядоченная пара {0, 1} не отличается от неупорядоченной пары {1, 0}.
- Сколькими способами можно выбрать двоицу (бригадира и его заместителя) в бригаде из 11 маляров?
- Сколькими способами можно выбрать пару игроков футбольной команды для выборочной проверки на употребление допинга?

Дополнение (от 16.07.2014)

В английском языке есть слова "pair" и "couple".

Comment: Ни "pair", ни "couple" в английском не несут оттенка упорядочения.

Answer (score 2):

Ежели вы создаете свой язык – как говорится, ветер в по... ой-ой, не то, не то. Флаг в руки и барабан на шею! Кто запретит?!

Comment: Прочитано про "не то, не то".

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, это слово будет воспринято так, будто употреблено с ироническим оттенком.
По аналогии с *троица* ("пресвятая троица - Трус, Балбес, Бывалый"))))))).

Слово *двоица * несколько устаревшее, а все устаревшие слова и выражения воспринимаются как ироничные.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ.

Comment: "пресвятая троица - Трус, Балбес, Бывалый". Где почерпнули?

Answer (score 0):

Разумно. Не бойтесь употреблять в речи устаревшие слова. Раньше наш язык был более певучим, поэтичным, менее заострённым, и поэтому устаревшие слова придают речи более одухотворённый, возвышенный оттенок. И, возможно, в ближайшем будущем слово "двоица" вновь станет общеупотребительным.

Comment: Поощрять таких разумных опасно. Лоб расшибут.